# Cannot find module 'react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js'

Tags: java, android, kotlin, react-native

After installing React native, I run following command:

> $ react-native init demoApp

And got this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
at Function.require.resolve (internal/module.js:16:19)
at makeMakeHMRConfig7 (/home/local/MPLLC/malwinder.singh/demoApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/babel-bridge.js:120:31)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/local/MPLLC/malwinder.singh/demoApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/babel-bridge.js:49:24)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
at Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/local/MPLLC/malwinder.singh/demoApp/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
```

What am I missing? How to fix this issue?

Comment: try to reinstall the react-native cli

Comment: Done. Still not working.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?Im stuck with the same error.

Comment: Yes. I installed required packages: create-react-native-app

Comment: would be nice if you gave a detailed solution for us beginners brahski.

Comment: You can find more answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659866/unable-to-resolve-module-react-transform-hmr-lib-index-js/52665506#52665506

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install react-transform-hmr
```

This solved the issue for me

Comment: yarn add --dev react-transform-hmr

Answer (score 1):

The below command fixed the issue for me

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```