# Unable to resolve module `./../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js`

Tags: react-native, react-redux

error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `./../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js` from `/ReactNative/UsermanagementNav/src/App.js`: The module `./../../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js` could not be found from `/ReactNative/UsermanagementNav/src/App.js`.

I have tried to install react-native-transform-hmr using

> npm i react-native-transform-hmr

but it does not solve my issue. i am using react-native 0.57.2 and react 16.5.0

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I got an answer.

Just try:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

command, it will work.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the issue.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 33):

> This issue only happens when react-native 0.57.2 is installed.
>
> It seems like the Metro Bundler has an issue resolving the paths when
>   started from `./node_modules/react-native/scripts/packager.sh`.
>
> Starting the Metro Bundler directly from the project directory works
>   for me. Can someone let me know if it works for them too?
>
> ```
> # Clean cache
> rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*; watchman watch-del-all
>
> # Start Metro Bundler directly
> react-native start
>
> # Now run `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios` in another tab
> ```

[Source](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21490#issuecomment-427240356)

Comment: Thankyou soo much brother.

Comment: I am using it in xcode so tell me how can i do it whatever you are saying?

Comment: Worked when used `react-native start --reset-cache` instead of `react-native start`

Comment: Yes you can also try this `react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: for me running metro bundler directly with --reset-cache have worked, however  this issue started when I updated my xcode to Version 10.0 (10A255)/ios12. My RN project was and still in react-native: 0.55.4. Thks for the answer!

Comment: This solves the problem when running react-native run-ios in the command line. But it does not help if you want to debug on a real device through Xcode... Any solution?

Comment: Please one more thing `npm cache clean --force`  and install npm again it will behelp you

Answer (score 13):

try clear cache using this commend .this method was worked for me

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 7):

you need to :

1. downgrade to react-native "0.57.1"
2. run :

   `npm install @babel/runtime`

Answer (score 6):

The work-around below has been confirmed to work on:

```
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "0.57.2"
```

**Work-around:**

```
# https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21490

# 1) Clean cache
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*; watchman watch-del-all

# 2) Open a *NEW* terminal tab and 
#    Start Metro Bundler directly from the project folder using:
react-native start  --reset-cache

# 3) Return to second project folder tab and run
# react-native run-android`
# or
# react-native run-ios`
```

Answer (score 4):

bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module /../react-transform-hmr/lib/index.js

This solution work for me. Only update node_modules\metro\src\reactNativeTransformer.js near line no.130

https://github.com/facebook/metro/commit/e595178fc859263cc2d88de08650d99c52bcc0d9

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fun workaround i discovered .
(Running on Windows 10 )
Open 2 Powershell windows .
In the first type  `react-native start --reset-cache`  
In the second  go to your folder path and type  `react-native run-android` 
works like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

This issues has been resolved in `React Native@0.57.3`, so you might want to cosider upgrading to that or later version at this point.

Just make sure you also update `React` and `React test renderer` to atleast version `"16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"`. **I have also migrated to use `React@16.6.0` whitout any issues.**

**React Native 0.57.3 changelog**

> **NOTE WELL**: when you upgrade to this version you **NEED** to upgrade react and react-test-renderer to version `"16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"` at least (next version will update to "first class support" for 16.6.0, and it will come soon - but you should be fairly safe using 16.6.0 anyway). Also, please check the Known issues section below, especially if you are using Xcode 10.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, do this :

```
npm install @babel/runtime
```

Then run this:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

and then run this one :

```
react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 2):

I was so stuck in this for like 3/4 days.
I tried every approach but none fixed my problem.
Finally I managed to solve this(for me), the following were my settings:

- npm -version = 6.4.1
- node -v = 10.11.0
- python --version = 2.7.14

Then during command "react-native init MyProject" the version it would install would be "0.57.2" which caused me the problem so the easy way that I came across was during init use

***>react-native init --version="0.55.4" MyProject***

rather than ***>react-native init MyProject***

It fixed everything for me and loaded the startpage on the installed apk on my device ( I am using a device rather than an emulator)

Hope this helps, I am really new to programming, sorry about my inability to explain this stuff more technical terms.

Best wishes

Comment: I have been stuck on this for 3 days too! I tried everything and this is the only solution that worked for me. #node10.11 #npm6.4.1 #python2.7 #windows10 #android8 #androidstudio #androidemulator

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and for me, the secret sause was:

To Update the react-native-cli with

```
npm install react-native-cli -g
```

Then, everything was running and working as expected.

My version is 0.60.5

Comment: i have mispelled my secrect sauce. But know it isn't a secret anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved by these steps,

```
- Close all the npm Terminal
- Open a new Command prompt and run react-native start --reset-cache
- Open a new Command prompt and run react-native run-android
```

Answer (score 1):

1) change react native version react-native "0.57.2" to "0.57.1" in your package.json
2) run yarn|npm install again.
3) kill all node processes `killall node`
4) test your app again.

most common reason for the problem can be using a physical device other than an emulator.
hope this issue will be fixed in future react versions.