# React Native Error: Unable to resolve module `./index`

Tags: react-native

I have a newly created application using React Native. The app contains a simple login form and a fetch query, nothing complicated, few css and components.

I tried to implement Facebook, and after a LOOOT of struggle, I stopped receiving Facebook errors, while now, I get this error which makes no sense when I run react-native run-android :

No screen shown, nothing, diretcly this 500 error.
I searched all over and over for a solution, I even added the form for Gradle, re-installed all npm packages after rm rf node_modules.. still the same error.

```
implementation ("com.facebook.react:react-native:0.58.5"){force = true}
```

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Used `npm start -- --reset-cache` to run Metro Bundler and it worked. Found this solution looking for the answer to the same issue, [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659866/unable-to-resolve-module-react-transform-hmr-lib-index-js) that helped me.

Comment: Can you describe this deeply to make it clear to the OP?

Comment: The problem was that initlally the project was built under expo, so index was deleted.

Comment: eL magnifeco!!!

Answer (score 4):

I think this question might be related to [Unable to resolve module `./index`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330641/unable-to-resolve-module-index/55349626#55349626) So the question is, did you try to run the app before you connected facebook? If it worked before then we might have a different issue. However, it's similar to this bug: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24112

A fix has been released a few hours ago. Please upgrade to react-native `0.59.2`.

```
react-native upgrade
```

The full guide on how to upgrade: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading

Comment: upgrading to `0.59.2` fixed it for me

Comment: In fact it appears to be nothing related to facebook

Answer (score 1):

Thats an error of your backendserver ... look inside the config and remove the module which can't be found

Answer (score 0):

You can run npm install then react-native upgrade to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

create a new project with react-native init "projectName"
go to "**`node_modules\react-native\scripts\packager.sh`**" of the new project you have created.
copy it and replace it with the one of the old project which is having issue...
This worked for me. I found out it was an upgrade to react-native 0.59.2 that caused it..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this (RN 0.61.2) by adding an index.android.tsx file at the project root (above ./src).

That file just contains:

`import "./src/App";`

Previously it worked fine with index.tsx in ./src, not sure why it broke as of 0.61.2.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```
react-native start -- --reset-cache
```

**Solution 2:**

make **metro.config.js** file at the root of your project and paste below code

```
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

**Solution 3:**
run these commands

```
rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-*; rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-*; watchman watch-del-all

# Start Metro Bundler directly
react-native start
```

Answer (score -2):

It is clearly written in the error

Unable to resolve module `./index` from `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projects/jobifier-mobile/.`: The module `./index` could not be found from `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/projects/jobifier-mobile/.`. Indeed, none of these files exist

Please check and see if you have given the correct path.

Comment: Given the correct path where ? the thing is that I don't understand the error, I don't know where a module called ./index is being set !