# Unable to resolve module `./index`

Tags: react-native

I've been receiving an unable to resolve module index in my code the past few days and have found a temporarily solution but am unable to find a permanent fix.

I've been receiving this error for the past few days and have found a temporary solution when I run "npm start -- --reset-cache", but whenever i run "react-native run-android" again, the same error pops up. This is the error.

Why is this error appearing and how can I solve it without using my temporary solution each time?

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from `c:\reactnative\a\node_modules\react-native\scripts/.`: The module `./index` could not be found from `c:\reactnative\a\node_modules\react-native\scripts/.`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
  * `c:\reactnative\a\node_modules\react-native\scripts\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  * `c:\reactnative\a\node_modules\react-native\scripts\index\index(.native||.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (c:\reactnative\a\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (c:\reactnative\a\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (c:\reactnative\a\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:283:16)
    at c:\reactnative\a\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:261:42
    at Server.<anonymous> (c:\reactnative\a\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:1038:41)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (c:\reactnative\a\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:99:24)
    at _next (c:\reactnative\a\node_modules\metro\src\Server.js:119:9)
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [25/Mar/2019:02:18:03 +0000] "GET /index.delta?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "okhttp/3.12.1"
```

Comment: can you post your package.json ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was caused due to a bug in the latest React Native version `0.59`: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24112

A fix has been released a few hours ago. Please upgrade to react-native `0.59.2`.

```
react-native upgrade
```

The full guide on how to upgrade: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading

Comment: Thank you! Yes this fixed it for me -- just changing `package.json` to `59.2`

Comment: when i change react native version to 0.59.2 it did not work but by changing it to version 0.58.6 it works perfectly

Comment: but the awful thing which bothers me is in last project i was able to work with version 0.59.1 but suddenly i can't

Comment: After upgrading, delete the `node_modules` folder, run `npm install` and then run `react-native start -- --reset-cache` once and see.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

This was due to an issue in the RN 
Reference : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1924

Comment: hi as i said it works but every time i must use it!

Comment: This was an issue in react 0.59.1....this is now fixed in 0.59.2....  So in your package.json file remove  "react-native": "0.59.1" and add "react-native": "0.59.2".......or in your project folder run this command "react-native upgrade"

Comment: when i change react native version to 0.59.2 it did not work but by changing it to version 0.58.6 it works perfectly!

Comment: but the awful thing which bothers me is in last project i was able to work with version 0.59.1 but suddenly i can't

Answer (score 1):

run

**react-native start -- --reset-cache**

then

**react-native run-android** *(in separate command line)*

works fine for me

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. delete `node_modules` folder
2. run `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure packager server is not running on next tab. I was stuck due to that.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the contents of `c:\reactnative\a\node_modules\react-native\scripts/.` which is the project directory of a project that works without errors and replaced to the project that has errors