# React Native Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` in node_modules/react-native

Tags: react-native

I am creating fresh react-native app:

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
react-native init FirstProject
cd FirstProject
react-native run-android
```

I see the following error message:

> 'Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from /home/alex/code/test2/FirstProject/node_modules/react-native/.'

By the way, file index.js was created at my project folder (/home/alex/code/test2/FirstProject/index.js)

This is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Try:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659866/unable-to-resolve-module-react-transform-hmr-lib-index-js

Answer (score 7):

I don't know the cause bro, 
Downgrade you react-native version to  0.58.5 (this worked for me)

```
react-native start -- --reset-cache
```

execute above command.

then do

```
react-native run-android
```

for more info refer this [discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23908)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by installing the lower version of React.

Follow the below steps

1. Delete the `node_moduled` folder by typing `rm -rf node_modules/` in the terminal
2. Delete the IOS and Android folders as well
3. Edit the `package.json` and keep the dependencies and devDependencies as follows (Do not change your other setting in this file)

```js
"dependencies": {
  "react": "16.6.3",
  "react-native": "0.58.5",
  //other dependencies 
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
  "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
  "jest": "24.1.0",
  "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.52.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3"
},
```

4. Run `yarn` or `npm install` this will add `node_modules` again in your project
5. Rum `react-native upgrade` to add `Android` and `ios` folder in your project

Best of luck

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this issue by downgrading react native version to 0.58.6

This issue is because of new version of react native.(0.59.*)

Step 1: Delete node modules folder and package-lock.json file

Step 2: Change react-native version in package.json dependencies to 0.58.6

Step 3: run npm install on project root directory in command prompt

Step 4: run command react-native run-android

Done!

Answer (score 2):

Just in case if anyone still have this issue, I have resolved it by resolving all possible extensions the app can support.
In my case the modules and components were having .jsx where App is having .js.

Finally got my issue through by updating file -
metro.config.js

```
resolver: {
    /* resolver options */
   sourceExts: ['jsx','js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'native', 'json'] //add here 
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue and these steps worked from me.
This is more like a quick fix:

- Downgrade the version of react and react-native from `0.59.1` to

`"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.0",`

- run `npm install` then `react-native upgrade --legacy` ,
- Replace the `android/app/build.gradle` by pressing `y`
- Rebuild you project `react-native start -- --reset-cache`
- Run `react-native run-android`

[Source 1](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23908#issuecomment-472747429)
[Source 2](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23908#issuecomment-473043927)

Answer (score 1):

I finally resolved the issue by downgrading to the previous version of react-native:

```
react-native init FirstProject --version 0.58.6
```

It seems that this issue is related only to the latest react-native, version 59.
Previous version of react works.

Thank you everyone !

Answer (score 0):

clean and install like below :

delete node_modules and run

```
 npm install
    npm link
    react-native run-android
```

Hope this works....

Comment: If you're going to "hope something works" at least explain WHY you think it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue as you have TRY to install `npm install` or `yarn install` .Try to run both in your project folder by terminal of your code editor.
It happen because of package only.if you don't upgrade your package it will show error. if you run `npm install` or `yarn install` it will install all package by default which are missing or which are not upgrade.
if your are then also getting same error try to run `npm install node` or`yarn install node`node package might have issue. then also it is issue then there might another problem.

There is another way you can download simple app code from **expo website** or **React native** try to build your project in it.